# Which software supports multiple users logging in remotely, simultaneously and independently into a Mac?

Tags: remote-desktop, macos

I would like to know if it is possible for multiple users to log-in remotely into a Mac system and doing their work independently at the same time?

Each user has his own desktop (window machine). Is this possible? If yes, which software does it require?

Answer (score 1):

This is supported by the standard [Screen Sharing](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/share-the-screen-of-another-mac-mh14066/mac) feature of macOS, according to [this answer on Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/256349/121968):

> macOS Sierra still supports multiple simultaneous connected users. In the example below Sierra is running in a VM and *admin* is logged in. *user* is a remote screen sharing session from the VM host machine (10.9.5) – an iMac – and *root* is a remote session from a MacBook Pro (10.11.6):
>
> [image]

If your clients are other Macs, they'll have a built-in Screen Sharing app; if you want to connect with Windows or other Unix clients, you can use [any client that supports the VNC protocol](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/24976/121968), e.g. [RealVNC](http://www.realvnc.com/).